# we get com.hazelcast.core.MemberLeftException when one hazelcast goes down in jetty session replication

Tags: session, jetty, hazelcast, embedded-jetty

We are using hazelcast 3.6.3 for session replication with jetty 9.4. The hazelcast config is

```
Config config = new Config();
    config.setInstanceName(HAZELCAST_INSTANCE_NAME);
    // logger config
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "slf4j");
    // config for session map
    MapConfig sessionMapConfig = new MapConfig();
    sessionMapConfig.setName(SESSION_MAP_NAME)
            .setBackupCount(2);
    config.addMapConfig(sessionMapConfig);
    // peer discovery with zookeeper
    config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    config.setProperty(GroupProperty.DISCOVERY_SPI_ENABLED, "true");

    DiscoveryStrategyConfig discoveryStrategyConfig = new DiscoveryStrategyConfig(new ZookeeperDiscoveryStrategyFactory());
    discoveryStrategyConfig.addProperty(ZookeeperDiscoveryProperties.ZOOKEEPER_URL.key(), serviceDiscoveryNode);
    discoveryStrategyConfig.addProperty(ZookeeperDiscoveryProperties.ZOOKEEPER_PATH.key(), "sessionstore/APP");
    discoveryStrategyConfig.addProperty(ZookeeperDiscoveryProperties.GROUP.key(), "cluster-name");
    config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getDiscoveryConfig().addDiscoveryStrategyConfig(discoveryStrategyConfig);
```

When one of the members of cluster goes down we get this in our logs

```
 2018-11-27 13:13:47,217 [WARN ] (1-thread-1) com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl  - [10.x.x.x]:5702 [dev] [3.6.3] Could not get results
com.hazelcast.core.MemberLeftException: Member [10.x.x.x]:5701 has left cluster!
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationMonitor$OnMemberLeftTask.run(InvocationMonitor.java:284)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:212)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
        at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponse(InvocationFuture.java:387)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponseOrThrowException(InvocationFuture.java:337)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.get(InvocationFuture.java:225)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.get(InvocationFuture.java:204)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl.addResultsOfPredicate(MapQueryEngineImpl.java:528)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl.invokeQueryAllPartitions(MapQueryEngineImpl.java:421)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.values(MapProxyImpl.java:637)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.values(MapProxyImpl.java:625)
        at
```

Why do we get an exception when we have backup of partitions enabled in session map config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MemberLeftException` is thrown when a member leaves the cluster during an invocation or execution but it is `RetryableException` which means it will be retried with the updated member list. So eventually it should heal itself.

OTOH I see that you're on 3.6.3 but latest stable version is 3.11, upgrading is a good idea considering there are many improvements and fixes since.